# Automate Tableau Download

Tags: python, selenium, mechanize, tableau-api

I want to automate the download of the customer portal in Tableau.  I have an admin account and need to download the CSV daily.  What is the best way to do this?

```
 browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
 browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
 browser.set_handle_referer(True)
 browser.set_handle_robots(False)

 browser.open("https://auth.tableausoftware.com/user/login")
 browser.select_form(name = 'login')
 browser['email'] = ''
 browser['login_password'] = ''

 browser.submit()
```

Which is not working?  I get cant submit the form?  What am i doing wrong, is there an easier way?

This is my error message:

Need to add this element and call click method, because calling submit()\n\ton the form causes failed submission if the form has another element with name or id of submit.\n\tSee: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit#Specification

and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I don't think this is possible even using the Tableau API. You're better off having your python script run the same sql Tableau is using. It will definitely be faster too since the script would be hitting the db directly

Comment: That's possible using tabcmd.http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm

Comment: @FirebladeDan, that is not exactly true. Depending on the size of the table, and the operations required, and whether Tableau is using extracted data (to a columnar format), Tableau can outperform a sql query.

Comment: You know Tableau creates sql and fetches from a datasource right? Read the tableau logs and tell me if that is clean sql... Tableau's generated sql is only optimized for columnar tables because this is the Tableau Extract Format. Copy your sql you're using for your data capture and run separately otherwise Tableau will take your query and provide overhead.

Comment: If the user is using Tableau just to query a table (with no fancy operators, just SELECT FROM), then yes, you're right. If the user is performing calculations inside Tableau, then it depends on how more efficient Tableau is performing those calculations than a sql statement that does the same thing.